# Schengen zone question

Tags: schengen

When assessing the time of entry/time of exiting the Schengen zone by plane, is the entry/exit time:

1. Time the flight lands/takes off?
2. Time of disembarking/boarding the plane? (This actually is the rule for presence in the UK).
3. Time of entry/exit via immigration?
   Thanks

Comment: For what purpose? Entry on or after the start of validity? Exit on or before the end of validity? Max duration? 90/180? For many it's the time you go through immigration, but for entry airlines will generally not let you board if the scheduled arrival is too early, for instance, even if by the time you reach immigration you would be the next day.

Comment: Why would the time matter?

Comment: Hi. I'm talking about the 90/180 rule. Why would it matter? Well, if plane lands 23:55 and you disembark 00:05, which day did you arrive, according to Schengen rules? I'm asking because I'm always butting up against my 90/180 limit.